# How to share wpf style setter

Tags: wpf, styles, resourcedictionary

I have the following ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="StyleComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <!-- Styles for ComboBox -->
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="StyleTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <!-- Styles for Textbox -->
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How is it possible to use only at one position the setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles in wpf can be inherited from another style.

```
<Style x:Key="baseStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
 </Style>


 <Style x:Key="boldStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}" TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
 </Style>
```

[source](http://wpftutorial.net/StyleInheritance.html)

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Style x:Key="baseStyle" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="StyleComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

            <!-- Styles for ComboBox -->
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="StyleTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

            <!-- Styles for Textbox -->
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: The OP has two different `TargetType`s

Comment: How is it a problem? Just set base styles target type to Control.

Comment: @Rafal how it is possible to share more different setters?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by more different.

Comment: @Rafal Once you do that, you're fine.

Comment: @Rafal i want to outsource the BorderBrush in a separate style and also the BorderThickness in a other style

Comment: I suppose merging more then two styles could be done. I never had a need to do so. Style is basically a collection of setters so you could write some code for it if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="Controlbase">
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
    <Style  x:Key="StyleComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Controlbase}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
        <!-- Styles for ComboBox -->
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="StyleTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource Controlbase}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
        <!-- Styles for Textbox -->
    </Style>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Curious if this worked for you. Need to be careful in that you're redefining the style of say a ComboBox as based on your Control base style. Presumably the control template is not affected by this as that would be bad. IOW A ComboBox is much more than just a simple control and needs to inherit the styles and preserve the control template of all that it means to be a ComboBox. IE Its a SelectorControl that inherits from an ItemsControl etc.

I wonder if rebasing its style would also cause it to prefer/use the default control template of a Control rather than retaining its "identity" as say a ComboBox.